# pylint custom checker: node.modname is empty for relative imports

Tags: python, pylint

I'm writing a custom pylint checker and am in `def visit_importfrom(...)` which is entered on statements like: `from base import package`.

When the import statement has a form like `from numpy import array` `node.modname == 'numpy'` as expected.

However when doing a relative import, such as a sibling package `from . import sibling_package`, `node.modname == ''` rather than the expected `'.'`. The same is unfortunately true with a statement such as `from .. import blah` which makes it impossible to determine the original statement without hacky string parsing.

Is anyone familiar with this and have an explanation?